# Joomla breadcrumbs with Virtuemart Cart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, breadcrumbs

When i click the shopping cart link. The breadcrumbs displays doble link titles like the one attached:[image: breadcrumbs]

and here is my code:

```
    <?php // no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); ?>
<div class="breadcrumb">
<span class="left"></span>
<ul>
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++) :

// If not the last item in the breadcrumbs add the separator
if ($i < $count -1){
if(!empty($list[$i]->link)) {
echo '<li><a href="'.$list[$i]->link.'" class="pathway">'.$list[$i]->name.'</a></li>';
} else {
echo '<li>'.$list[$i]->name.'</li>';
}
//echo ' '.$separator.' ';
}else if ($params->get('showLast', 1)) 
{ // when $i == $count -1 and 'showLast' is true
    echo '<li>'.$list[$i]->name.'</li>';
}
endfor; ?>
</ul>
<span class="right"></span>
</div>
```

how can i eliminate the first uRL?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
if($i!=0){

    if($list[$i - 1]->name != $list[$i]->name){
    echo '<li>'.$list[$i]->name.'</li>';
    echo $separator;
    }
}
```

Another way this only happen in this page then you can remove the first li using jQuery

find the nth child option and remove It.

Hope this may help you..